# git inside virtualbox fails with "Unable to create temporary file '<mountpoint>/<pathToRepo>/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX'"

Tags: git, virtualbox

Situation description: our company enforces use of highly questionable vpn, super-obsoleted, man-in-the-middle enhanced, and which also fails frequently. I become anoying quickly, but I failed to tame it via routing tables/iptables. So I'd like to run it in virtualbox only, as other forms of process isolation did not work for me / was unsuccessful. It is bizarre, I know, but I want to install fresh distribution and don't want to poison it with this. So I have some directory in host OS, which is shared into virtual box. User in host os and virtualbox has same uid,gid. Shared directory is mounted using `sudo mount -t vboxsf aaa /tmp/a -o uid=22823,gid=22823`. Should be fine. So I run `git fetch origin` on quest system, so I'm not running command on host, I'm running command in quest on data shared from host. But:

```
git fetch origin 
remote: Enumerating objects: 73, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (73/73), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/tmp/a/projectName/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Operation not permitted
fatal: index-pack failed
```

but then:

```
touch /tmp/a/projectName/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX
```

without any issue under same user, same with opening it/writing into file using arbitrary editor. TMPDIR is not set, neither on host or guest OS, setting it does not work.

The message itself does not seems to describe real issue. What can cause this behavior, what can I examine?

Answer (score 1):

Git does not use `TMPDIR` for creating its temporary files because it must rename them atomically in place, and `TMPDIR` may or may not be on the same filesystem.  If it is not, then using it would prevent an atomic rename from working.

It is not usual to see `EPERM` in this case, since the more normal case would be `EACCES`, which indicates a permission failure somewhere on the directory.  This error is likely coming from the VirtualBox shared file system.

My guess here is that it is unhappy with the fact that Git is passing a file mode of 0444 and `O_RDWR` at the same time.  That is explicitly permitted by POSIX, but some NFS implementations have that problem as well, although they usually return `EACCES`.

You may wish to avoid the use of the vboxsf file system here and switch to SSHFS instead.

Comment: My preference with VirtualBox and the like is to give them virtual disks and let the OS inside do its own file system. Either way it's good to avoid vboxsf, though...

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm little bit angry at myself, that I didn't have idea that it can be caused by vboxsf. However I cannot test sshfs, that idiotic vpn/it's setting does not allow ssh anywhere but to company machines. If you have any idea how to proceed, please suggest. But namely all my attemps with routing tables etc failed.

Comment: Ok, I will do it otherwise around. Start crappy-vpn® inside of guest OS, clone repo there, and ssh from host into guest using guest repo as intermediate 'origin'. That seems to work at cost of several GB of storage loss.